# Alternatives to standard DOM events like "onclick" and "onmouseover"?

Tags: javascript, html

So I was poking around GMail the other day and ran across some interesting behavior...

I was in my Inbox and decided to click on a message.  Having Firebug open at the time, I decided to take a quick look at the message link, just because I'm curious.

I noticed that GMail doesn't use DOM level 0 or DOM level 2 events for this operation...  meaning that there is no "onclick" property on the DOM element or there was no event subscribed via "addEventListener".

My question then is:

**What alternative strategies are there to the standard DOM event APIs for doing things like "onclick" and "onmouseover"?**

Comment: The event is called "click". "onclick" is a property used to store the click handler (function).

Comment: How can you see in Firebug if an event listener is attached to a DOM element?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there aren't. It's possible that the handler is on a parent element and the event is being captured there which is why you didn't see a handler on the element itself.

Comment: It looks like this may be the case... There is an outer div higher up the chain with a click event... this may be capturing everything and delegating to other methods based on some portion of the element (eg. ID or some other property).  It is hard to tell though because everything is minified.  I didn't know that you could access the "inner" element clicked from the event object... pretty cool stuff!

Comment: You might want to look at this page: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html It's been very helpful to me in the past. Also, quriksmode is a great site.

Comment: @Polaris The `target` property of the `event` object points to the DOM element that initiated the event. Therefore, you can attach a handler to the `document` object and still know which element was clicked.

Comment: @takteek... Thanks for the link, that was very helpful!  I also liked how it explained a bit of history and the different models IE and W3C follow.